# Regular Expression for an expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

```
jobID\":14197
```

I need to extract this jobID value using the regular expression extractor in Jmeter.

Comment: @Fallenhero I have tried this jobID\":(.+?)

Comment: Try `jobID.*?(\d+)` and use first captured group.

Comment: @Tushar it is working fine now..correct value is extracted. Thank you.

Comment: @user3627319: your regex is almost correct, you need to escape the `\`, so use `jobID\\":14197`

Comment: Please add your regex attempt _into the question_, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter uses [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/regexps.html) so the relevant regular expression would be:

```
jobID\\":(\d+)
```

where:

- `\` - escape character for the backslash
- `()` - grouping
- `d` - matches any digit
- `+` - non greedy match (don't stop after first digit)

See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual for more information.

You can test your regular expressions against live response using [View Results Tree listener in RegExp Tester mode:](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

[image: Debug JMeter Script]